# Can I set a reminder for Google Tasks based on their due date?

Tags: email, reminder, google-tasks

Is it possible to be notified before a task is due, similar to how you can set notifications for events on Google Calendar?

Comment: new to this site......how can i delete my answer? delete button is for voting to close this post :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Tasks does not provide email alerts.

As mentioned by @Antoops, you can set alerts for Google Calendar events which may provide the functionality you are looking for.

It would be nice to see Google add the ability to set alerts for tasks, but I think they have left it out on purpose (since a task list is something you should check regularly by design vs. being pushed alerts/reminders)

[This support thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=30d55cb9dc43396f&hl=en) has further reading on this feature request.

Comment: The support thread as an answer gives invitation to use Google Inbox instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have checked what Morad replied and it is correct. You can use [r:HH:MM] in the notes section of the tasks to set a reminder. You will see a reminder only when you are using an app like Astrid or Gtasks that provides a reminder facility while syncing to Google Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The MyTasks App for Iphone seems to access the Remind me x minutes before the due date and integrates perfectly with GTasks.  Not sure where the Alert data is stored but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a reminder using the notes section of the task.. For example if you want the reminder to be on 11:00 in the due date, then you set the due date normally and then type [r:11:00] inside the notes of the task. It worked for me..

Comment: Huh? I tried this, but got no reminder. What kind of reminder did you get? An email, a popup window, an SMS or something else?

Comment: Yeah sorry, maybe you need an application that parses this as a reminder.. I use CalenGoo and I get a popup reminder when doing that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short script I wrote that takes tasks that have a due date, puts them on the calendar (7 am) and marks them as done! (then you'll get a calendar alert for them .)

http://msftb.blogspot.ca/2015/09/why-cant-you-get-calendar-alerts-from.html